# Can I apply stability tests to a sub collection of components in a system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of ODEs of the form
\begin{align*}
\dot{x_1} &= x_1 f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3) \\
\dot{x_2} &= x_2 f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3) \\
\dot{x_3} &= x_3 f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3) \\
\dot{s_1} &= \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial s_1}(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3)s_1(1-s_1) \\
\dot{s_2} &= \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial s_2}(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3)s_2(1-s_2) \\
\dot{s_3} &= \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial s_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3)s_3(1-s_3)
\end{align*}
which represent a game theory scenario (prisoner's dilemma) with three populations $x_1,x_2,x_3$ with strategies $s_1,s_2,s_3$. The populations grow indefinitely but I want to show that $s_1,s_2,s_3$ always converge to 0, the Nash Equilibrium for the game. Numerical integration strongly suggests that this is in fact the case. How could I go about showing that $s_1=s_2=s_3=0$ is a "stable fixed point" for the components $s_1,s_2,s_3$? Can I somehow transform the system so that I could employ traditional stability tests? (i.e. linearizing and looking at eigenvalues)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can look at the (partial) linearization in the $s_i$ variables. In your case this is relatively easy because $s_1 = s_2 = s_3 = 0$ is always a fixed point (or actually, invariant set) of the system. Secondly, the linearization in the $s$ variables at zero is precisely given by the diagonal matrix
$$
A = \textrm{diag}(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial s_1},
                  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial s_2},
                  \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial s_3}).
$$
So these diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of the linearization also, but note that you have to evaluate these along solution curves of your system, in particular in their limit behaviour, which as you say is that the $x_i(t)$ go to infinity.

In this case it is sufficient that the eigenvalues are uniformly bounded below zero as that provides a bound for a stable spectrum. (Note that when the eigenvectors change over time, things can be more complicated and negative eigenvalues are not sufficient for stability.)

For more details see for example Coppel's book "Stability and asymptotic behavior of differential equations", although I'm not sure it treats this case with partial linearization, which can be viewed as stability as the invariant manifold $\{ s_1 = s_2 = s_3 = 0 \}$.

Comment: So do I look at the eigenvalues $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial s_i}, i = 1,2,3$ evaluated at the point $s_1 = s_2 = s_3 = 0$ as a function of time and look at the limiting behavior of corresponding to $x_i (t)$'s going to infinity?

Comment: Indeed, that is, you have to look for the values of $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial s_i}(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t),0,0,0)$ and check that these are all uniformly below zero for any actual solutions $x_i(t)$ with $s_i = 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem. If this indeed solves your problem, would you maybe tag my answer as such?